# Two objects colliding

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Can you explain to me how this works?

> A cart with a weight of 200 tonnes (200 * 10^3 kg) hits another stationary cart with a weight of 20 tonnes (20 * 10^3kg) with the speed of 2m/s. How far will they travel together when the friction coefficient is 0,07 and they travel along with the same speed after the collision.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: @stafusa I completely understand that this is not a place for homework answers. Just wanted someone to explain me this thing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## How to do it

This sounds like home-work, so I will give you the **procedure**, not the actual answer.

1. Find out the objects' combined momentum before the collision.

   Remember: momentum in a collision is preserved, **kinetic energy** is not. <sub>(*)</sub>
2. After the collision, use momentum and mass to find their speed.

   Remember: their speed is **equal**, they did not bounce off of each other.
3. After finding the speed you can find the kinetic energy they have.

   Remember: All that kinetic energy must be spent in order for the objects to stop.
4. Find the friction force that the objects exert on the ground.

   Remember: the friction force is proportional to weight, and to the friction coefficient.
5. Recall the relationship between force, distance travelled and work performed (i.e. energy spent). From this it is trivial for you to find the distance travelled.

Good luck! :-)

<sub>(*) I failed one question — in the shape of two humans colliding — on a senior high-school physics test for getting this bit wrong.</sub>

<sub>This approximate conversation followed:</sub>

> <sub>— What do you mean? Energy is preserved, yes?</sub>
>
> <sub>— Nope, only momentum. Some energy is lost.</sub>
>
> <sub>— What?! Where does that go?</sub>
>
> <sub>— Well... broken bones, torn muscles, tissue damage... things like that.</sub>
>
> <sub>— Oh...</sub>

Comment: Be careful with your wording.  Momentum in a collision *is* conserved.

Comment: Leading to the correct answer but in a wrong sequence/wording

Comment: @Alchimista Yeah, I accidentally kicked the words about. Thank you. Edited now.

Comment: What do you mean by *inertia* in this context?  The only ways I know to quantify inertia are *mass* and *moment of inertia*, and I can't understand your usage with those definitions.

Comment: @garyp Fixed again...